# Perl program to look for k-mer with specific sequence

Tags: perl

I am trying to enhance a perl program I have previously written so that it recognizes top 1000 length 23 k-mers that ends with GG and print out the k-mers that only appears **once** in the sequence. However, no matter where I add the reg exp, I am unable to get the expected result.

The code I have:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict;
use warnings;

my $k           = 23;
my $input       = 'Fasta.fasta';
my $output      = 'Fasta2.fasta';
my $match_count = 0;

#Open File
unless ( open( FASTA, "<", $input ) ) {
    die "Unable to open fasta file", $!;
}

#Unwraps the FASTA format file
$/ = ">";

#Separate header and sequence
#Remove spaces
unless ( open( OUTPUT, ">", $output ) ) {
    die "Unable to open file", $!;
}

<FASTA>;    # discard 'first' 'empty' record

my %seen;
while ( my $line = <FASTA> ) {
    chomp $line;
    my ( $header, @seq ) = split( /\n/, $line );
    my $sequence = join '', @seq;

    for ( length($sequence) >= $k ) {
        $sequence =~ m/([ACTG]{21}[G]{2})/g;

        for my $i ( 0 .. length($sequence) - $k ) {
            my $kmer = substr( $sequence, $i, $k );

            ##while ($kmer =~ m/([ACTG]{21}[G]{2})/g){
            $match_count = $match_count + 1;
            print OUTPUT ">crispr_$match_count", "\n", "$kmer", "\n" unless $seen{$kmer}++;
        }
    }
}
```

The input fasta file looks like this:

```
> >2L type=chromosome_arm; loc=2L:1..23011544; ID=2L;  dbxref=REFSEQ:NT_033779,GB:AE014134; MD5=bfdfb99d39fa5174dae1e2ecd8a231cd; length=23011544; release=r5.54; species=Dmel;
CGACAATGCACGACAGAGGAAGCAGAACAGATATTTAGATTGCCTCTCAT
TTTCTCTCCCATATTATAGGGAGAAATATGATCGCGTATGCGAGAGTAGT
GCCAACATATTGTGCTCTTTGATTTTTTGGCAACCCAAAATGGTGGCGGA
TGAACGAGATGATAATATATTCAAGTTGCCGCTAATCAGAAATAAATTCA
TTGCAACGTTAAATACAGCACAATATATGATCGCGTATGCGAGAGTAGTG
CCAACATATTGTGCTAATGAGTGCCTCTCGTTCTCTGTCTTATATTACCG
CAAACCCAAAAAGACAATACACGACAGAGAGAGAGAGCAGCGGAGATATT
TAGATTGCCTATTAAATATGATCGCGTATGCGAGAGTAGTGCCAACATAT
TGTGCTCTCTATATAATGACTGCCTCTCATTCTGTCTTATTTTACCGCAA
ACCCAAATCGACAATGCACGACAGAGGAAGCAGAACAGATATTTAGATTG
CCTCTCATTTTCTCTCCCATATTATAGGGAGAAATATGATCGCGTATGCG
AGAGTAGTGCCAACATATTGTGCTCTTTGATTTTTTGGCAACCCAAAATG
GTGGCGGATGAACGAGATGATAATATATTCAAGTTGCCGCTAATCAGAAA
TAAATTCATTGCAACGTTAAATACAGCACAATATATGATCGCGTATGCGA
GAGTAGTGCCAACATATTGTGCTAATGAGTGCCTCTCGTTCTCTGTCTTA
TATTACCGCAAACCCAAAAAGACAATACACGACAGAGAGAGAGAGCAGCG
GAGATATTTAGATTGCCTATTAAATATGATCGCGTATGCGAGAGTAGTGC
CAACATATTGTGCTCTCTATATAATGACTGCCTCTCATTCTGTCTTATTT
TACCGCAAACCCAAATCGACAATGCACGACAGAGGAAGCAGAACAGATAT
```

and so on...

The expected outcome (print out the 23k-mers with GG ending that only appear **once** in the sequence) I am hoping to get:

```
>crispr_1
GGGTGGAGCTCCCGAAATGCAGG
>crispr_2
TTAATAAATATTGACACAGCGGG
>crispr_3
ATCGTGGGGCGTTTTGTGAAAGG
>crispr_4
AGTTTTTCACATAATCAGACAGG
>crispr_5
GTGTTGGATGAGTGTCCTCTGGG
>crispr_6
ATAGGTTGGTTGTTTTAAAAGGG
>crispr_7
AAATTTTTGTTGCCACTGAATGG
>crispr_8
AAGTTTCGAACTACGATGGTTGG
>crispr_9
CATGCTTTGTGGAAATAAGTCGG
>crispr_10
CACAGTGGGTGTTTGCACCTCGG
.... and so on
```

The current code I did create a fasta file with following:

```
>crispr_1
CGACAATGCACGACAGAGGAAGC
>crispr_2
GACAATGCACGACAGAGGAAGCA
>crispr_3
ACAATGCACGACAGAGGAAGCAG
>crispr_4
CAATGCACGACAGAGGAAGCAGA
>crispr_5
AATGCACGACAGAGGAAGCAGAA
>crispr_6
ATGCACGACAGAGGAAGCAGAAC
>crispr_7
TGCACGACAGAGGAAGCAGAACA
>crispr_8
GCACGACAGAGGAAGCAGAACAG
>crispr_9
CACGACAGAGGAAGCAGAACAGA
>crispr_10
ACGACAGAGGAAGCAGAACAGAT
.... and so on
```

while if I remove the

```
for (length($sequence) >=$k){
$sequence =~m/([ACTG]{21}[G]{2})/g;
```

and add the ##while ($kmer =~ m/([ACTG]{21}[G]{2})/g){

```
 while ($kmer =~ m/([ACTG]{21}[G]{2})/g){
```

I am getting fasta file (with results which is not numbered correctly and unable to distinguish between duplicated and unique sequences):

```
>crispr_1
CATTTTCTCTCCCATATTATAGG
>crispr_2
ATTTTCTCTCCCATATTATAGGG
>crispr_3
TATTGTGCTCTTTGATTTTTTGG
>crispr_4
GATTTTTTGGCAACCCAAAATGG
>crispr_5
TTTTTGGCAACCCAAAATGGTGG
>crispr_6
TTGGCAACCCAAAATGGTGGCGG
>crispr_7
ACGACAGAGAGAGAGAGCAGCGG
>crispr_8
AAATCGACAATGCACGACAGAGG
>crispr_91
TATTGTGATCTTCGATTTTTTGG
>crispr_93
TTTTTGGCAACCCAAAATGGAGG
.... and so on
```

I have attempted to move the regex around my code, but none of them generated the expected result. I do not know what I did wrong over here. I have not add the exit the program when count reaches 1000 into the code yet.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Can you provide us with some (cut-down if necessary) input along with the output that you want from that input. It's very hard to help when you can't see the data you're dealing with.

Comment: @DaveCross I've provided the input file; it's just a general fasta file containing genetic sequence. Thanks.

Comment: I am confused: The first expected line (the one for `crispr_1`) is: `CATTTTCTCTCCCATATTATAGG` but there are no consecutive sequence in the input file you show matching that. How did you arrive at that specific sequence?

Comment: @HåkonHægland Good catch over there. I did not attempt to match the sequence directly to the file; so I didn't notice that. The specific sequence is like a hint given to me, to know what is the first few sequences I would expect.

Comment: @HåkonHægland I think I found the reason for the inconsistency, it was expecting me to print out the 23-kmers that appear only 'one time' in the whole sequence. That is why my output doesn't match the expected one.

Comment: Your "expected result" is totally unclear, on the other hand the last attempt that returns `CATTTTCTCTCCCATATTATAGG`, `ATTTTCTCTCCCATATTATAGGG`, `TATTGTGCTCTTTGATTTTTTGG` seems correct.

Comment: @CasimiretHippolyte I've updated the question with more descriptions. While the last attempt seemed to be correct, the code is unable to distinguish between duplicated (kmer that appears > 1 time) and unique (kmer that appear just 1 time) results. The expected result only prints out the unique kmer, which only appear 1 time. And I do not understand why the code isn't counting correctly. Thanks.

Comment: I just reformatted your code. It looked randomly indented to me. If you don't like it, feel free to revert my edit. I used [`perltidy`](http://perltidy.sourceforge.net/) in case you're wondering.

Comment: @Sunny Please fix the expected output so that it matches with the given input file. Then it will be easier to understand what you are trying to achieve :)

Comment: @HåkonHægland The input file is just a small part of the whole fasta file, I just posted it so people have an idea what the format looks like. It's impossible for me to post the whole file as it was just too big. So what I wanted is just a way to print out 1000 'unique' 23kmers ending with GG that each only appear once in a large drosophila gene sequence. My current output file seems to just look for all the 23kmers ending with GG and does not even count correctly. Hopefully this would explain what I want to achieve.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure I understand your question completely, but could the following be what you need.

```
<FASTA>; # discard 'first' 'empty' record

my %data;
while (my $line = <FASTA>){
    chomp $line;
    my($header, @seq) = split(/\n/, $line);
    my $sequence = join '', @seq;

    for my $i (0 .. length($sequence) - $k) {
        my $kmer = substr($sequence, $i, $k);

        $data{$kmer}++ if $kmer =~ /GG$/;
    }
}
my $i = 0;
for my $kmer (sort {$data{$b} <=> $data{$a}} keys %data) {
    printf "crispr_%d\n%s appears %d times\n", ++$i, $kmer, $data{$kmer};
    last if $i == 1000; 
}
```

Some output on a file I have is:

```
crispr_1
ggttttccggcacccgggcctgg appears 4 times
crispr_2
ccgagctgggcgagaagtagggg appears 4 times
crispr_3
gccgagctgggcgagaagtaggg appears 4 times
crispr_4
gcacccgggcctgggtggcaggg appears 4 times
crispr_5
agcagcgggatcgggttttccgg appears 4 times
crispr_6
gctgggcgagaagtaggggaggg appears 4 times
crispr_7
cccttctgcttcagtgtgaaagg appears 4 times
crispr_8
gtggcagggaagaatgtgccggg appears 4 times
crispr_9
gatcgggttttccggcacccggg appears 4 times
crispr_10
tgagggaaagtgctgctgctggg appears 4 times
crispr_11
agctgggcgagaagtaggggagg appears 4 times

. . . .

ggcacccgggcctgggtggcagg appears 4 times
crispr_50
gaatctctttactgcctggctgg appears 4 times
crispr_51
accacaacattgacagttggtgg appears 2 times
crispr_52
caacattgacagttggtggaggg appears 2 times
crispr_53
catgctcatcgtatctgtgttgg appears 2 times
crispr_54
gattaatgaagtggttattttgg appears 2 times
crispr_55
gaaaccacaacattgacagttgg appears 2 times
crispr_56
aacattgacagttggtggagggg appears 2 times
crispr_57
gacttgatcgattaatgaagtgg appears 2 times
crispr_58
acaacattgacagttggtggagg appears 2 times
crispr_59
gaaccatatattgttatcactgg appears 2 times
crispr_60
ccacagcgcccacttcaaggtgg appears 1 times
crispr_61
ctgctcctgggtgtgagcagagg appears 1 times
crispr_62
ccatatattatctgtggtttcgg appears 1 times

. . . .
```

**Update**
To get the results you mentioned in your comment (below), replace the output code with:

```
my $i = 1;

while (my ($kmer, $count) = each %data) {
    next unless $count == 1;
    print "crispr_$i\n$kmer\n";
    last if $i++ == 1000;
}
```

**To answer** my own comment to get *first* 1000.

```
<FASTA>; # discard 'first' 'empty' record

my %seen;
my @kmers;
while (my $line = <FASTA>){
    chomp $line;
    my($header, @seq) = split(/\n/, $line);
    my $sequence = join '', @seq;

    for my $i (0 .. length($sequence) - $k) {
        my $kmer = substr($sequence, $i, $k);

        if ($kmer =~ /GG$/) {
            push @kmers, $kmer unless $seen{$kmer}++;
        }
    }
}

my $i = 1;
for my $kmer (@kmers) {
    next unless $seen{$kmer} == 1;
    print "crispr_$i\n$kmer\n";
    last if $i++ == 1000;
}
```

**Answer** To check for uniqueness of final 12 chars ending in GG, the code below achieves that.

```
        if ($kmer =~ /(.{10}GG)$/) {
            my $substr = $1;
            push @kmers, $kmer unless $seen{$substr}++;
        }

my $i = 1;
for my $kmer (@kmers) {
    my $substr = substr $kmer, -12;
    next unless $seen{$substr} == 1;
    print "crispr_$i\n$kmer\n";
    last if $i++ == 1000;
}
```

Comment: What I am trying to achieve is to print out the first 1000 23kmer sequences end with GG that only appears 1 time. Thanks!

Comment: @Sunny I've thought it over and my solution won't print the *first* kmers ending in GG. It prints any of the kmers that appear once in the file in random order. If you need the *first* 1000, then a different solution would be necessary.

Comment: I checked the result output from your updated code, and the head -100 and the tail -100 do match up with the expected output result. And it doesn't seem to produce in random order as well. So I don't think there's something wrong with this solution. Thanks a lot for checking!

Comment: I used the diff command and made sure there is no difference between the expected output and the output this code produces. Thanks!

Comment: Just for future reference, if I'm looking to print out only the 23-kmers with unique 12 nucleotide endings, do I just change the regex to ($kmer =~ /.{10}GG$/) ? Thanks.

Comment: I tried out the code, it doesn't seem to work as expected.

Answer (score 0):

Actually, this code line

```
$sequence =~m/([ACTG]{21}[G]{2})/g;
```

this line is just for the regex match, if you try to print this `$sequence`, it will surely print out the original result.

please add the code segement like this

```
if($sequence =~/([ACTG]{21}[G]{2}$)/g) 
{


}#please remember to match the end with $.
```

BTW,It looks like the multiple for loop to parse this data is not very reasonable, the parse speed is without the best-efficiency.

Comment: Eric this methodology doesn't work, it will print out blank fasta file.